# .httacces redirect from http to https for a page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have /secure page, and I need redirect users which open this page to https protocol. But all others should open only with http. I want to do this with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^secure(.+?) https://site.com/secure$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But on a secure page I get cyclic forwarding. How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^secure https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^secure http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I try to use this solution, but I get cyclic forwarding.

Comment: Which URL didn't work for you? Can you try this in a different browser?